# Better using UIColor

Tags: objective-c, memory

I have a simple question:
What is better for any reasons - to use `[UIColor somecolor]` each time you setting it or make a property/ivar and set it in viewDidLoad and then use it everywhere in Controller?

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) UIColor *someColor;
someColor = [UIColor redColor];

view1.color = someColor;
view2.color = someColor;
...
```

Why?

Making property for UIColor is too time-consuming and i think it's not necessary for such a little object. Is there a fast way to get over this without making property?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<s>The convenience methods with the pattern "someColor" allocate memory each time you're calling them.</s> This is less efficient then allocating the memory once and assigning it to a property (i.e. a variable which points to the part of allocated memory).

In general dereferencing is much less expensive than allocating.

EDIT: Since what @Mats mentioned: Scratch that, since the convenience methods return singletons it makes no difference.

Comment: No, they don’t. They return a singleton. Try `NSLog(@"%p %p", [UIColor redColor], [UIColor redColor]);`.

Comment: I had no idea. Thanks for pointing that out. I edited my original answer.

Comment: @Mats if it's a singleton, than no other questions, your comment is the best. Please post a full answer and i'll check it.

Comment: It is not a singleton, it is a class variable which I imagine is created lazily.  The fact that Apple have bothered to do this is your answer though. Best.

Answer (score 1):

You should usually prefer using a property which has the pointer to an object, this can improve the performance of your application with big objects instead of call a method to have the access to it. In this case UIColor is not a big object and so you don't have big benefits.

Anyway, when you have an object to use several times in a class you should have a property for it.

Answer (score 0):

Best is :

```
- (void) changeColor:(UIColor *)color 
{
    view1.backgroundColor = color;
    view2.backgroundColor = color;
    view3.backgroundColor = color;
}
```

or arguably :

```
[@[view1, view2, view3] makeObjectsPerformSelector:@selector(setBackgroundColor:) withObject:[UIColor redColor]];
```

Like this, you instantiate the object once when you call the method, and you don't need to store it in a property since each view already stores it. Should you want to change it in the future, just call the method again, while if you had a property, by the law of OOP, changing the property would not change the color of the views...